# How to concatenate sibling arrays using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Given a JSON like:

```json
[
  {
    "items": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    "items": [3, 4]
  },
  {
    "items": [8, 9]
  }
]
```

how do you concatenate `items` with JQ into a single array like:

```json
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  4,
  8,
  9
]
```

A playground with this example: https://jqplay.org/s/r1RvAir27V

I need it to calc the length of all the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatten`:

```
map(.items) | flatten
```

<sup>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LHSIC65et7)</sup>

---

Or, `map()` the `items` instantly

```
map(.items[])
```

<sup>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1vCNnTcwdy)</sup>

---

Or one of the many other options like:

- [`[ .[].items ] | add`](https://jqplay.org/s/L2c2JddSKN)
- [`[ .. | scalars ]`](https://jqplay.org/s/47WzsXLSSZ)
- [`[ .[][][] ]`](https://jqplay.org/s/_fXjbnj0e7)

---

All of those commands will produce:

```json
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  4,
  8,
  9
]
```

Comment: Or `[..|scalars]` or `[..|numbers]` or even `[.[][][]]`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways to construct the array in this particular class of cases would be:

```
[.[][][]]
```

This has the advantage of brevity and not using
`flatten`, which should only be used with a full understanding of its semantics.

However, since the ultimate goal is to count the elements, it might be better to avoid constructing the array altogether, e.g. by using

```
def add(s): reduce s as $x (null; .+$x);
```

Now you have another range of options, e.g.

```
add(..|objects|.items|length)
```